# If $a_{n}$ and $b_{n}$ diverge to infinity, show that $a_{n} b_{n}$ and $a_{n} + b_{n}$ diverge to infinity also

Tags: real-analysis

I don't really know where to start. I have tried to find an epsilon where $a_{n}$ is greater than epsilon, but I don't think I am approaching the problem the right way

Comment: Can you write down the definition of a sequence diverging to infinity?

Answer (score 0):

$a_n \rightarrow \infty$ means for any $N>0$ and $M>0$, $a_n>M$ for all $n>N$, i.e. this sequence is unbounded. You guess a bound, those elements at the end will go over the "bound". Clearly the same $N$ (pick the maximum if they are different for $a_n$ and $b_n$) for a specific $M$ that works for $a_n$,$b_n$ will work for $a_nb_n$ and $a_n+b_n$ asumming $a_n>1$ and $b_n>1$.

Answer (score 0):

$a_n$ diverges to $\infty$ means that for any $M\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n_M$ such that for $n>n_M$ we have $a_n>M$

$b_n\to\infty$ means that for any $L\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $n_L$ such that for $n>n_L$ it happens that $b_n>L$

$a_n+b_n\to\infty$ because for any $P\in\mathbb{R}$ we take $L$ and $M$ such that $L+M>P$ and 
$n_P=\max(n_M,n_L)$ so for $n>n_P$ we have  $a_n+b_n>M+L>P$

and we can take $L$ and $M$ such that $LM>Q$ for any $Q\in\mathbb{R}$ and index $n_Q=\max(n_M,n_L)$ such that for $n>n_Q$ we have $a_nb_n>LM>Q$

*QED*